# Control Direction of Motor

Tags: motor, switches, wireless

I have a Smart Switch (Sonoff Dual WiFi Wireless Smart Switch), and I control it through a Google Home. It works as a contact, like if it was a switch:
[image]

I want to control an electric blind, that has this connections:
[image]

The neutral is always connected, and, if you power up "Phase Up" the blind goes up, and if you power up "Phase Down", it goes down.

The endstop is located internally of the blind motor.

I have another switch, for manual control, with 2 buttons, up and down, and when you click one, the other disconnects automatically, so you can't press both at the same time.

Any ideas of how to join the 2 circuits, without being able to power up the 2 Phases of the Motor, and being able to control anytime, from the manual switch, or the wireless switch.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUvX5N.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Simplest circuit.*

The simplest solution is to replace the local or remote switches with changeover contacts as shown in Figure 1.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fAJkWU.png)</sup>

*Figure 2. Use relays if you can't use changeover switches.*

Down from eleven relays to two.

Comment: I was checking it, and the problem is that the blind has an intern endstop, so, if I say to Google Home "Open the blind", it will switch the trigger, but it will remain pressed, although the blind is stopped. With the Local buttons I don't have that problem, because when you press a button, the other one gets released, but with the wireless I can't do that. Also, if I first open the blind wirelessly, and then close it, the motor will break, because the 2 contacts will receive power.
So, in brief, if I switch any of the Remote triggers, it will remain pressed. So you think it's possible?

Comment: I haven't a clue. I've added in the up and down limit switches. Does Google Home not have a timeout feature that allows you to have the switch energise for, say, 20 s and turn off again.

Comment: I thought yes, but it seems that it's not yet possible... :(
Thank you anyway.

Comment: I will accept the answer because it works, and it answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found this solution...
[image]
Please, if any of you can check it.

Comment: The only problem is that there are about 11 220v relays... A bit expensive...